# How to build uncontrolled component with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I translate this **uncontrolled component** to **react hooks** (and avoid multi render of the input field):

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    const {onInputChanged} = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" ref={this.input} onChange={onInputChanged}/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at some examples of functional components with Hooks and take a stab at it. Then, if you're stuck, ask for help with that? This is not a 'how do I do it' question, this is a 'do it for me' request.

Comment: I think that this is a good example of how to write uncontrolled component in react hooks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your component to a functional component and use hooks you can do this way:

```
import React, { useRef,useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {

},['the props you write here will trigger the re-render when they change'])
const MyForm = (props) => {
  const input = useRef(null);
  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" ref={input} onChange={props.onInputChanged} />
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Do i have to use one more time ```useRef``` if I have two ```input``` elements?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `useRef` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export const MyForm = (props) => {
  const input = useRef(null);
  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" ref={input} onChange={props.onInputChanged} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.